# What is eating up space in Nexus Repository

Tags: repository, nexus, diskspace, amazon-ebs

We have a Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager with 13TB of EBS volume. We do not have the enterprise edition and the version that we are using is 3.25.1-04.
We are currently running out of storage but we are not sure what is eating up space. When we analyzed the charts/images are taking up 6.5TB of space, we are not sure where the other 7TB is getting used. Does anyone have any idea how we can find out where the other space is being taken up? We run daily the "compact blob store" job that cleans up the stale images but it does not seem to work and free up space. We are clueless here as to how to figure out the root cause. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below GitHub project. The script can be help to clear storage space on Nexus repository by analyzing the stats generated by the script. The script feature prompt-based user input, Search/Filter the results, Generates CSV output file and Print the output on console in a tabular format.

[Nexus Space Utilization - GitHub](https://github.com/shamsher-ansari/nxrm-space-utilization)

You may also refer below post on the same.

[Nexus Space Utilization - Post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/shamsher-ansari-0a056a16a_nexus-repository-manager-activity-6967465798349017088-u20H?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop)